# Starting new Activity not from the MainActivity file

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

I need to open new activity (using fragments if it's important) and I'm on a different file then the main activity so the code :

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Is not good enough for me because I'm getting :

...is not an enclosing class ERROR referring : CurrentActivity.this

Does someone knows how to solve it ?

Thanks...

Comment: Have you searched in SO before asking question???

Comment: Post your activity code, please

Comment: @Clairvoyant Yes and  i didn't found an answer that solved my issue  . if you don't  have something useful to add you are welcome to ignore this post

Comment: For future reference: `this` is a reference to the current object when used **within** class instance method or a constructor, it cannot be used from outside to get object instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass to `Intent` constructor an instance of `Context` class. So if you need to start new activity from `Fragment` you shall write `new Intent(getActivity(), NextActivity.class);` and start it like `getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);`

Answer (score 1):

If your are in a Class use this code:

```
public class AnyClassName{

    Context context;

    public AnyClassName(Context context){
    this.context = context;
   }

   public void AnyMethod(){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, NextActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(myIntent);   
  }

}
```

If you are in Fragment then use this:

```
 public Class AnyFragmnet extends Fragment{

  //all default methods which i am not declaring

  public void AnyMethodName(){
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), NextActivity.class);
  getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are some ways to solve this problem as I know. The main thing is you have to get a `context` object to start another activity. Let's try one of below:

1. If you are using `fragment`, try to call `getActivity()` when start activity from fragment as:

   ```
   Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), NextActivity.class);
   getActivity.startActivity(i);
   ```
2. Create an your `Application class extends Application` for your project and then call `getApplicationContext()` instead of call `getActivity();`
3. Pass an `Context` object to your `fragment` and then use it instead of `getActivity()` or `getApplicationContext()`